# Optimize Database - Repair

Tags: database, optimization, repair

I'm trying to speed up my site and found this site:http://www.computingunleashed.com/speed-up-wordpress-ultimate-guide-to-make-sites-super-fast.html, which gave the following recommendation:

Just like the hard disks the wordpress database also gets fragmented. So optimizing the wordpress database too can speed up your site.

For optimizing the wordpress database of your site, visit the cpanel of your hosting provider.

Use phpMyAdmin to optimize your database: Log in to phpMyAdmin, select all the tables, and then repair and optimize.

I use Godaddy and FileZilla: Is there a way to do this through the godaddy website? Through filezilla? I'd like to know my options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [phpMyAdmin](http://community.godaddy.com/help/article/5942) on GoDaddy.com